# Read random txt line, split strings by : and write in textboxes

Tags: vb.net, split

I've got two textboxes and I want make account generator which will read random line from txt file on website and write it into textboxes. So, I want to read random line(just one) from a text file, where email and password are separated by : so .txt file would look like email@site.com:password , write data before : in textbox1(email) and write data from the same line after : in textbox2.

.txt file looks like this:

```
email1@example.com:password1
email2@example.com:password2
email3@example.com:password3 etc....
```

I cannot figure out how to split this strings, any help will be appreciated, thanks anyway :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3s2KXfN.jpg  Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: what if password contains a `:` ? Also, it is legal for e-mail addresses to contain `:` characters.

Comment: Never mind, I put data without : in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    tbxEmail.Text = String.Empty
    tbxPassword.Text = String.Empty
    Dim lines As String() = getData("URL_OF_FILE")
    Dim lineCount As Integer = lines.Length
    Dim randomValue As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((lineCount) * Rnd()))
    Dim line As String = lines(randomValue)
    Dim parts As String() = line.Split(New Char() {":"c})
    Dim email As String = parts(0)
    Dim password As String = parts(1)

    tbxEmail.Text = email
    tbxPassword.Text = password

End Sub

Function getData(url As String) As String()
    Dim client As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim data As String = client.DownloadString(url)
    Dim returnValue As String() = data.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Please not that this is a synchronous request, meaning it will "freeze" your application for the duration of the request.

Comment: This one worked. Thanks :) Just, can u explain me what is 'c' at {":"c}  doing there? :D

Comment: ":" alone would be a single-character long string. the 'c' behind it (":"c") converts this single-character string into a Char (single character). visual basic has its quirks.

Comment: @n0pt3x It's not often I see a low-reputation user contributing positively to the site. Well done, keep it up :).

Comment: @n0pt3x shows data but only first line, I press button once more time, it gets same data. Am really unlucky...

Comment: that shouldn't (necessarily) be happening. how big is your sample size? if you're only using very few entries, this can indeed happen.

As an example, this is a series of random numbers between 0 and 2: 1100202220122122021120110110022122